# EF6 Database first decimal precision control

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

We are using Entity Framework 6, MVC 5, database first approach. In the MS-SQL 2004 database are many fields with Scale=0. For example, a particular field is defined numeric(3,0). All is well as displayed on the form (whole number) and restricting the value range from 0 to 350.  But when MVC sends this field back to the database it throws this error: "Parameter value '999.00' is out of range". We have researched this issue and set the Precision to 3 and Scale to 0 for get/put as previously recommended in other posts.

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this problem.  Thank you.

Comment: What is the type of the parameter in MVC?

Comment: As recommended in question 3504660 we tried public DecimalPropertyConfiguration HasPrecision(
byte precision,
byte scale )

Comment: The question you are referring to is about EF Code First. Since you're using database first you cannot use `DecimalPropertyConfiguration`. What I ment with my question is: what is the type of the C# parameter you are trying to save? Can you add the relevant MCV code to your question?

Comment: In database first c#-EF-MVC is it even possible to return a whole number value to the SQL database when the field is defined in the database as NUMERIC(3,0)?. I am the database designer only, not a programmer, and the programmers are very inexperienced with MVC, etc.  They insist only INTERGER types will work with SQL-MVC to represent whole numbers. I really need someone with more experience to verify this before redesigning the database for this project. I appreciate your interest and advice. Thank you.